# What is a way to customize the "Please DocuSign....." message in emails sent by DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

What is a way to customize the "Please DocuSign....." message in emailes sent by DocuSign?

Currently it's just

> John Smith,
>
> Please DocuSign xxx.pdf
>
> Thank You, John Smith

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Found it at last. It is **emailBlurb**

Regards,